# iOS 7 Delegate Not Responding In A Specific Circumstance

Tags: objective-c, ios7, delegates

I have a custom delegate that will work at times and not work at other times.  Let me explain...

There are three classes.  Class A is the main class, Class B is a modal Page Sheet display and Class C is a modal Full Screen display.

Class A displays Class B using a segue.  Before Class B is displayed, Class A registers the delegate for Class B.  When Class B is dismissed, Class A responds to the delegate.  This works properly.

Class A displays Class B using a segue.  Before Class B is displayed, Class A registers the delegate for Class B.  Class B calls Class C for display.  After Class C is dismissed and Class B is dismissed, the delegate between Class A and Class B does not respond.  If I then display Class B from Class A a second time and dismiss Class B, the delegate responds.

When there are only two classes in the chain the delegate operates properly.  When the third class is displayed, the delegate between Class A and Class B stops working.

The delegate is only between Class A and Class B.  Class C does not have this delegate.  There is a different delegate between Class B and Class C.  The delegate between Class B and Class C does work properly.

Class A/B delegate works:
Class A ==> Class B

Class A/B delegate does not work, but Class B/C delegate does work:
Class A == Class B ==> Class C ==> Class B ==> Class A

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was answered here: [Multiple Delegates in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774808/multiple-delegates-in-ios)

Delegates are a 1 to 1 relationship and multiple delegates down the even chain will not work well.

I am switching to the Observer methodology rather than delegates.