# UITextfield with multiple delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am using [JJMaterialTextField](https://github.com/juanjoguevara/JJMaterialTextField) custom UITextField class. It has some delegates for animation placeholder etc..I want to use some other delegates too for UIViewController which uses that class. If I write down delegate.self for JJMaterialTextField class object in UIViewController, I does not perform its own delegates, it perform only delegates methods in UIViewController. But I want to that it should perform both delegate methods. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: can you put your code here?

Answer (score 5):

Done use delegates in the view control, instead use this

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

It will behave like delegate it will fire when text changes, there are also other selectors textFieldDidBegin.. etc.
This way you wont interrupt the delegates.

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly considered a bad idea if you need multiple delegates. Delegates are all about 1-1 relationship.

Please read the answer here, it will give you pointers on how you could proceed with observers or with notifications

[Multiple Delegates in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774808/multiple-delegates-in-ios)

If you don't want to go with the recommendations above take a look at first and second answer on how you can do it, basically create a object that holds references to multiple delegates, then you can just look over them and post delegate methods that way:

[Delegation to multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278857/delegation-to-multiple-objects)